# How do I activate autofocus on the Arducam OV5640D module?

Tags: computer-vision, camera, microcontroller, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am using the [Arducam OV5640D module](https://www.arducam.com/product/5-mp-ov5640d-cmos-af-camera-module-1-4-inch-module/), directly connected to an ESP32-S3 Devkit C-1 N8R8 ([user guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/hw-reference/esp32s3/user-guide-devkitc-1-v1.0.html)).
My camera module appears to be very similar to the [one used for testing](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/OV5640_Camera_Board_(C)) in the [ESP32-OV5640-AF library](https://github.com/0015/ESP32-OV5640-AF), however the camera is not focusing.

I have tried implementing the basic example in the Arduino-IDE.

I can confirm the camera emits a click when it is connected to a power supply, which seems to confirm that the autofocus coil is actually connected.